# What do the question marks in the Xcode project navigator mean?

Tags: xcode

I was working on my Xcode project when I suddenly saw question marks in my Xcode project navigator. What does this mean?

Comment: Perhaps a little screenshot would help clarify what you are referring to.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe new users can post a screenshot.

Comment: Please share more details about your problem

Answer (score 4):

[image: File navigator with unadded file marked with question mark]

I believe you're referring to this question mark. It indicates that the file has not yet been added to source control. If you right-click the file and select "Source Control" you should be able to add it.

Comment: With me, as I added new files, some automatically added, but some didn't. Any idea why that happens?

Comment: @MikaelWeiss Typically when you create a new file via Xcode, it automatically adds it to git. When you create the file outside of Xcode, it generally doesn't. You can also look at Preferences>Source Control>General and check whether it's configured to add/remove files automatically (but the default is that it does). I have seen Xcode get confused many times about git, however, so sometimes it just makes a mistake.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: I have this same symptom, but I suspect it has a different cause.

I am familiar with the issue Rob Napier describes. In my case, this is not a new file in my git project. It has been there for a week or two and has been modified by several previous “git commits” with no problem. Also, when I do a `git status` at the command line it shows as **modified** the files marked as **?** by Xcode.

In my case I had two files, one about 20 lines long and one about 150 lines long. I moved about 140 lines from the big one into the little one. Now Xcode marks both as **?** instead of **M**.